# AWS EKS cluster does not connets with secret manager

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager

We are unable to connect our AWS EKS cluster with AWS SECRET MANGER. SECRET MANAGER is being connected with VPC. The deployed EKS cluster version is 1.16 while the latest is V1.19.

Please comment if any one had a same issue or worked on same problem.

Comment: how did you try to connect from your pod in the first place? can you paste the error in your question?

Comment: @gohm'c thank you for comment. We have solved the issue and I have written the possible solution in comments.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved the issue.

The solution to above problem was,
The nodes are connecting with secret manager via vpc endpoint and the connection between nodes and vpc endpoints was breaking. We fixed it and it's working now.